# What is the difference between an RDN, a DN, and a CN in LDAP?

Tags: ldap

I'm reading two ([link1](http://firstyear.id.au/blog/html/2016/06/20/the_ldap_guide_part_1_foundations.html), [link2](http://firstyear.id.au/blog/html/2016/07/05/the_ldap_guide_part_2_searching.html)) articles on LDAP and they make mention of Relative Distinguished Name (RDN), Distinguished Name (DN) and CN which is supposed to be the same thing as an RDN.

I understand an RDN to be a key in a key-values pair for a node in an LDAP directed graph, but the author doesn't say much about what these terms mean...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can recommend [LDAP for rocket scientists](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/), very nice and thorough intro to the protocol

To answer your question:

- distinguishedname: full path of the object in the tree. So if the ldap server has a base of `dc=domain,dc=tld` and the object is in the container `ou=users`, then the dn could be `cn=object,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=tld`
- rdn is in the example `cn=object`, because it is relative to `ou=users,dc=domain,dc=tld`.

If the object was in `ou=otherusers,dc=domain,dc=tld`, then the rdn would still be `cn=object`, but then it would have a different dn: `cn=object,ou=otherusers,dc=domain,dc=tld`.

So the rdn is relative to its parent.

And the common name cn is just an attribute. Sometimes the cn and the rdn have the same value. Other times, the rdn is uid=user (instead of cn=user), like most unix ldap servers do. So the dn would then be `uid=user,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=tld`. And that object could have a cn attribute as well to make it even fuzzier.

The differences have to do on what kind of object is being referenced, because every type of object has a different set of objectclasses that define what attributes it may (or may not) have.

The book is free to read, by the way.

Comment: FYU `cn` is "common name", not "canonical name".

Comment: fyi, I assume. FYU could be easily mistaken for something else ;-). In AD is canical name the convention, in other ldap directories is indeed common name an option. In my experience, canonical name is more usual in most professional environments.

Comment: Whoops, that's an unfortunate typo sorry about that! Anyway. The AD documentation says that `cn` is the LDAP projection of AD's `Common-Name` attribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-cn; this aligns with the standard LDAP schema defined in RFC 4519: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4519#section-2.3

Comment: There _is_ a `Canonical-Name` (constructed) attribute in AD, btw, but it is projected to LDAP as `canonicalName`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-canonicalname

Comment: ok, you convinced me, I modified the answer. Thanks!